# 0 entites created when creating bulkloader.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, bulkloader

I'm getting 0 entities transferred when trying to create the bulkloader.yaml running the command below:

```
appengine create_bulkloader_config --filename=bulkloader.yaml --url=https://dev-dot-mysite.appengine.com/_ah/remote_api
```

In my app.yaml, I have _ah configured

```
- url: /_ah/remote_api
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
  login: admin
  secure: always

- url: /.*
  script: ...
```

I'm getting the following.

```
02:01 PM Creating bulkloader configuration.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20131113.140100
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
Please enter login credentials for dev-dot-gmm-repros.googleplex.com
Email: ---
Password for ---: 
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20131113.140100.sql3
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-results-20131113.140100.sql3
[INFO    ] Connecting to dev-dot-mysite.appengine.com/_ah/remote_api
[INFO    ] Downloading kinds: ['__Stat_PropertyType_PropertyName_Kind__']
[INFO    ] Have 0 entities, 0 previously transferred
[INFO    ] 0 entities (8402 bytes) transferred in 101.2 seconds
```

When I open the bulkloader.yaml, I see:

```
# Autogenerated bulkloader.yaml file.
# You must edit this file before using it. TODO: Remove this line when done.
# At a minimum address the items marked with TODO:
#  * Fill in connector and connector_options
#  * Review the property_map.
#    - Ensure the 'external_name' matches the name of your CSV column,
#      XML tag, etc.
#    - Check that __key__ property is what you want. Its value will become
#      the key name on import, and on export the value will be the Key
#      object.  If you would like automatic key generation on import and
#      omitting the key on export, you can remove the entire __key__
#      property from the property map.

# If you have module(s) with your model classes, add them here. Also
# change the kind properties to model_class.
python_preamble:
- import: base64
- import: re
- import: google.appengine.ext.bulkload.transform
- import: google.appengine.ext.bulkload.bulkloader_wizard
- import: google.appengine.ext.db
- import: google.appengine.api.datastore
- import: google.appengine.api.users

transformers:
```

---

What could be going wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Bulkloader entities are created from 'Datastore Statistics' which are generated periodically. If you look at your app management console, there will be a section for it. If no statistics exist, then no entities will be generated.

On the dev-server you can force the statistics to be generated immediately, but on production, I'm not sure if there's another way to force it immediately